# I want to show Icon on rightButtonImage by react-native-vector icon and react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to show right button on navigation var, but nothing rendered.
Please give me solution or some advice.

[image]

Error

> ExceptionsManager.js:73 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Environment

```
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0"
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router />
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Actions, Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import Home from './components/Home';
import Menu from './components/Menu';

class RouterComponent extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {bookIcon: null}
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        Icon.getImageSource('ios-book', 30).then(source => 
        this.setState({bookIcon:source}));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="container">
                    <Scene
                        key="home" component={Home}
                        initial={true}
                        title={"Home"}
                        rightButtonImage={this.state.bookIcon}
                        rightButtonIconStyle={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                        onRight={ () => Actions.Menu() }
                    />
                    <Scene
                        key="menu"
                        component={Menu}
                        title={"Menu"}
                    />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )
    }
};
export default RouterComponent;
```

- Home.js and Menu.js just show Text component

Thank you for reading my problem.

Comment: You can try this rightButtonImage={require('this.state.bookIcon')}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hideNavBar={true}` in your `<Scene>` to hide the default header of router-flux and use a fully customizable header like [Native-base's](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref) header instead of it.

```
<Scene key="pageKey" hideNavBar={true}>
```

I tried it. And I fully customize my headers in every page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `hideNavBar` props for your Home component Scene in `Router.js`

   ```
   <Scene
     key={'home'}
     component={HomeComponent}
     hideNavBar
     title='Home'
   />
   ```
2. Use [NavigationBar](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar) component in your `Home.js` component

   ```
   import NavigationBar from 'react-native-navbar';
   import { Icon } from 'native-base';

   ...

   const rightButtonConfig = {
     title: 'Save',
     tintColor: 'blue',
     handler: () => console.log('Saved'),
   };

   const titleConfig = {
     title: 'Home',
   };

   <View>
     <NavigationBar
       title={titleConfig}
       rightButton={rightButtonConfig}
       leftButton={
         <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' onPress={() => Actions.pop()} />
       }
       style={styles.navbarStyle}
     />
   </View>
   ```

This is the screenshot will looks like.

[image]

Using this way, you can fully customizing your navigation bar.